# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file even if file was explicitly opened before writing

Tags: python

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


strFilinnhold = None
strTekst = None


root = Tk()

strTekst = input("Text: ")

file_object = open("Prøvetekst.txt", "w")


def skrivfil():
    file_object.write(strTekst + "/n")
    file_object.write("Hyggelig!")

button_1 = Button(root, text="Print text", command=skrivfil)
button_1.pack()

file_object.close()

root.mainloop()
```

My aim is to be able to enter text in the `tkinter` window and have it write to the text file. Why do I get an I/O error?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Python. All the statements at the file-level (both the `open` call and the `close` call get executed when the source file is loaded. When the `skrivfil` function actually gets called (sometime later) the text file isn't open.

Answer (score 2):

`file_object.close()` is called before the `mainloop`. By the time you get a chance to press the button, the file is closed indeed.